# Should meta tags be HTML-encoded?

Tags: html, standards

I generally HTML-encode any user generated content that I render on my website, so ampersands become `&amp;` and so on. I was wondering if this should be done (from a standards point of view) to any dynamically generated meta tag throughout a site?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Absolutely. All content within the HTML document must be encoded this way.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to encode `href` attribute of `a` tags.

Comment: @gamliela: It depends if it's html5 or not. To be standards compliant in anything xml based (aka atom or rss feeds) you definitely should. With html5, the situation is a little bit trickier (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19442133/8313 for more incredibly well researched information). When in doubt, encode your ampersands.

Comment: hmm... nice one! I didn't know that. So although it's ok to skip href encoding in html5 in some scenarios, to be on the safe side it's better to html-encode the urls (after the regular url-encode).

Answer (score 18):

If you mean something like this:

```
<meta name="description" content="Some stuff, other stuff &amp; even more stuff!" />
```

Yes, you need to encode the ampersand, and other special characters, to entities so your meta tags validate.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. So for example quotes don't close the content attribute for a meta element which would trigger invalid HTML.